# Laravel backpack: CRUD for polymorphic relations

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-backpack

***Edit: I have figured out a way to do it using custom field and column types. If there is any interest, I will try to post my solution here, please let me know.***

---

I recently switched over to *Laravel Backpack* to manage my Admin Panel, but I am having a major issue right now.

I have `Pages`, `Articles` and `Titles` in my Database.

A `Page` or `Article` can have many `Titles` (each for a different language, a german title, english title, etc.), so they are connected via polymorphic 1:n relation:

```
public function titles()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Title', 'titleable');
}
```

Now, when I edit my Page (or Article), **I want to also be able to edit all related titles**. From what I understood, [this is not possible at all](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/CRUD/issues/339) in backpack and I am quite surprised that there is no native support to show a model's polymorphic relations when editing it.

Did I miss something or is this not possible at all with backpack?

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: I think this would be possible if you create your own [custom field type](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/v2.0/docs/crud-custom-field-type). What have you already tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I have solved it now after days of digging with a custom field type and some hacky - possibly ugly - stuff. I still find it incredible that such a totally basic functionality isn't documented *anywhere*. Not even a bounty brought any idea. Apparently Laravel Backpack works well for very basic stuff, but gets a pain on more advanced scenarios. Cheers.

Comment: That was my findings when I last worked with it. Given that it’s a paid package, you could potentially approach the developers and ask them for help in improving your implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - In the end I think it *is* a good package, but somewhat lacks simplicity/documentation for trickier cases with advanced relationships.

Comment: Just put up a pivot table with columns id,title_id, titleable_id, titleable_type, table name titleable. Then in Title model: `public function titleable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }`

Comment: Then define in Title model: `public function articles()
 {
  return $this->morphedByMany("App\Models\Article","titleable");
 }
 
 
 public function pages(){
  return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\Title','titleable');
 }`

Comment: And finally define in both `Page` and `Article` : `public function titles(){
  return $this->morphToMany('App\Models\Title', 'titleable');
 }`

Comment: You can save a title with `$title_ids[] = Title::updateOrCreate(array('title' => $title['title']),$title)->title_id;` And link it to Pages and Articles like this: `$page->titles()->sync($title_ids,true);`

Comment: Thank you @user3647971, as I said in the original question, I managed to do it. I already had the relations set-up correctly, what I needed was some kind of backpack-logic to change related polymorphic relations, which I managed to do using custom fields.

Comment: Hey @Adrenaxus i also have same problem. Can you please post your solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: Hello @Dev, unfortunately I had to abandon Laravel backpack due to other problems related to more complex scenarios that I  wasn't able to find a proper solution for. I don't have the code anymore. However, I used [custom fields](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.0/crud-fields#creating-a-custom-field-type) to solve the problem. Within a custom field, you can basically do whatever logic you want and even output N fields like I did for my languages. Hope this helps a bit, sry for not being able to post code.